# How to remove black shade in the Drawable image in Android?

Tags: android

How to remove black shade in the Drawable image in Android?[image]

```
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);

        mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(d);
        listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
//    listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);   

        overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "", "");      
        mapOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);      
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

        mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used to display the Drawable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass an `Overlay` class and override the `draw()` method. Like this:

```
public class MyOverlay extends Overlay
{
    .....
    // obtain the BitMap of the image you want to draw on map
    .....

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        .....
        // draw the BitMap on the canvas        
        .....

        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
    }
}
```

The shadow is the default behavior of using `OverlayItem`.